# What cpu and memory will pod use if not specified in manifests?

Tags: kubernetes

If you do not define a request/limit for your cpu and memory in pod, deployment or stateful or namespace default, what will be the request and limit for that pod's cpu and memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default behavior will be to **use all available resources** on the node the Pod is deployed to. This hard fact can be gleaned from the K8s documentation at several places, e.g. [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/limit-range/).

So, one should always set limits on Pods. One can enforce defaults with [Limit Ranges](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/limit-range/) and ensure that Pods within a namespace don't starve other namespaces of resources with [Resource Quotas](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/resource-quotas/).